# process not outputting it's last row C#

Tags: c#, process, plink

I'm trying To run Plink via C# 
using this code

```
        public void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, bool EventWhenExit , bool IsWaitBeforeStart = true)
    {
        process = new Process();
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceivedEvent);
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // Gets or sets the application or document to start.
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;//Gets or sets the set of command-line arguments to use when starting the application      
        if (IsWaitBeforeStart) Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (EventWhenExit)
        {
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_Exited);               
        }

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        PID = process.Id;

        ProcessInputStream = process.StandardInput;

    }
```

When I run Plink (using this arg : `-telnet #IPAddr`)
I notice that last row only fires when I close the process .
My guess is that it keeps the last row until last row signal or something like that fired

How can make the process (not only Plink of-course ) to fire every thing it has in it's buffer and not when special signal like fired (like process exit or new line )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeginOutputReadLine()` waits for a newline character or the end of the stream. Unfortunately there is no `BeginOutputRead()` method that provides the behavior you desire. You do have access to `process.StandardOutput` though (a `StreamReader`), on which `Read()` operations do return whenever data is available.

Currently a *line* in a console application is "finished" as soon as it is terminated by a newline character. Since for this last line no newline character was outputted yet, you'd have to somehow determine whether it has finished or not. Consider the following example:

```
Console.Write("This is the ");
Console.Write(" plink output ");
Console.Write(" that I'm trying to read");
LongRunningActivity();
Console.Write(".");
Console.WriteLine();
```

You could receive these segments of data separately. When is the line finished? Before `LongRunningActivity()`?

So when attempting to read data before a newline character, you'll have to think of some rules to determine whether the message has completed.

Example of performing this task in a separate thread:

```
...
process.Start();
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(ReadFromStreamReader), process.StandardOutput);

void ReadFromStreamReader(object state)
{
    StreamReader reader = state as StreamReader;
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int chars;
    while ((chars = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        string data = new string(buffer, 0, chars);
        OnDataReceived(data);
    }

    // You arrive here when process is terminated.
}

void OnDataReceived(string data)
{
    // Process the data here. It might contain only a chunk of a full line
    // remember to use Invoke() if you want to update something in your form GUI
}
```

Comment: I still trying to get my head around this probelm , can you please explain how can implement the wait for data or reading the standardOutput ?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka I'm afraid I added to my answer only to show that things get _more_ complicated.

Comment: @LordTitiKaka can you explain what you're currently missing? It is something conceptual or just code to read from the `StreamReader`?

Comment: my problem is that I need to connect to server with username and password but when Is that after I prompt the user to enter username  the screen remains empty because of what you mentioned and I guessed , the "Password" is not printed on screen . 
my application is winform , so I cant just add some while loop to read the streamreader .
I need to implement an event to fire when streamreader is not empty

Comment: I'll rethink my problem , and post another question ... thanks